# LinqPad 5 treating previous lazy loaded navigation properties as non-lazy loading. Why?

Tags: linqpad

My LinqPad 5 has recently started treating all my navigation properties that were configured to use lazy loading as not lazy loading. This behavior is shown by the fact that when there is a navigation link on a result set and I click on it the screen simply displays a blank page instead of expanding to show the sub record.

I tested this code that was previous working and it now no longer uses lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

It was the security settings for my internet connection of my browser. I had upped the level of security for intranet and trusted sites. This caused the hyperlinks in LP to not function correctly.